# Pandas Merge Many Rows of One Dataframe into Fewer Rows of Second Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Is there an easy way to merge two dataframes such that df2 adds all its rows with matching 'on' values as new columns in df1? Open to other methods of joining the data as well.

e.g.
Matching on Course Offering Code and User Id

```
df1:
```

| Course Offering Code | User Id |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 |
| 001 | 2 |

```
df2:
```

| Course Offering Code | User Id | Assignment | grade% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | A01 | 65 |
| 001 | 1 | A02 | 85 |
| 001 | 1 | A03 | 95 |
| 001 | 1 | A04 | 64 |
| 001 | 2 | A01 | 87 |
| 001 | 2 | A02 | 86 |
| 001 | 2 | A03 | 82 |
| 001 | 2 | A04 | 90 |

I had tried `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['User Id', 'Course Offering Code'])` and was hoping for the following:

desired_df

| Course Offering Code | User Id | Assignment_x | grade%_x | Assignment_y | grade%_y | Assignment_z | grade%_z | Assignment_a | grade%_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | A01 | 65 | A02 | 85 | A03 | 95 | A04 | 64 |
| 001 | 2 | A01 | 87 | A02 | 86 | A03 | 82 | A04 | 90 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this one with [**`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) :

```
def flatten_cols(df):
    df.columns = ['_'.join(map(str, x)) for x in df.columns]
    df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[-1]))]
    return df

out = (
        df1
          .merge(df2, on=["Course Offering Code", "User Id"], how="left")
          .assign(idx=lambda x: x.groupby(['Course Offering Code', 'User Id']).cumcount()+1)
          .pivot(index= ["Course Offering Code", "User Id"],
                 columns= "idx", values=["Assignment", "grade%"])
          .pipe(flatten_cols)
          .reset_index()
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out.to_string())

  Course Offering Code  User Id Assignment_1 grade%_1 Assignment_2 grade%_2 Assignment_3 grade%_3 Assignment_4 grade%_4
0                  001        1          A01       65          A02       85          A03       95          A04       64
1                  001        2          A01       87          A02       86          A03       82          A04       90
```